# What size wire do I need for this 850' run?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I would like to run an underground wire 850ft using a 15amp breaker to run some lights, television/satellite and maybe a small appliance in my man cave. I have a 30amp panel in my man cave. What size of wire do I need?

Comment: You're probably on the verge, if not over the edge, of where a pair of transformers will cost you less than the wire you'll need without them, by letting you use smaller wire at higher voltage and lower amperage.

Answer (score 5):

### That kind of distance is not really practical at 120V.

You are better off hunting down a domestic 5 KVA 120/240–240/480V isolation transformer, sometimes seen on Craigslist in the $100 neighborhood. That will allow you to use 240V for the long haul, which will shrink the wiring need considerably.

- 2-wire+ground 6 AWG aluminum for the most basic needs
- 2-wire+ground 2 AWG aluminum for up to two 120V circuits.

Using copper here isn't even stupid.  You'll find out why when you start pricing wire lol.

Jumper the transformer primary for 240V (not 480V) and connect the 850’ long supply hot wires to it.

Jumper the transformer secondary for 120/240V and feed 3 wire hot-neutral-hot to the 30A panel.

This 30A unit is now a **main** panel!  You must jumper neutral to ground and you will need local ground rods just like a house.

Wiring it as 120/240V is overkill honestly, but it will Leave open the possibility of getting a SMALL 240V "mini-split" for heating and cooling.  Make sure you use the 2 AWG aluminum if you ever hope to do that.

### Or forget the grid and go local solar/battery

850' of 2-2-2-4 is going to cost more than a DIY solar/battery system, unless you need a huge battery.  Solar panels are cheap - 50 cents a watt often. Add 2-6 used golf cart batteries that can't make it 18 holes anymore and you're in good shape.  Many loads (lights, USB charging) can run directly off 12V* which eliminates need for an inverter.  For bigger 120V loads you can add an inverter, but only need to run it when those loads are in use.

Some internet routers, set-top boxes like Roku, and even some TVs can run straight on 12V.  But you are better off cutting power to them when not in use, as their vampire load is considerable.

Also note that the times when you need A/C are also times when the sun is shining. Further, putting solar on standoffs 6-12" above the roof so wind gets under it, effectively puts the shed into shade, greatly reducing A/C need.

* 12 volt USB chargers are easier to find **than eggs**. Every gas station, drug store, convenience store, cell phone store, grocery, has them *on racks at the register* as they are that popular.

Comment: As a detached building with a panel, this would need its own grounding rods no matter how the power gets there, would it not? (Just trying to build/reinforce my own knowledge base).

Comment: @FreeMan -- it depends on if the panel is a true subpanel (fed by a feeder) or a mere disconnecting means (fed by a branch circuit or MWBC)

Comment: @FreeMan Yes, yes, yes, 1000 times yes! The voltage gradients across 850 feet can be rather considerable, and you want your shed grounds to be grounded to local dirt, moreso than the house which could be 100V higher due to voltage gradients across the earth. This is why outbuilding subpanels need ground rods. You still need the ground wire for fault clearing, but I would have a local ground rod even in a "single circuit w/disconnect" situation.

Answer (score 1):

850 feet is a really long run at normal distribution voltages.  There's a reason the PoCo won't give you more than a 600 ft service drop without a transformer.

Southwire's handy-dandy voltage drop calculator says you'll need at least #3 Cu or #1/0 Al for a 5% voltage drop, and #1/0 Cu or #3/0 Al for 3%.

[Southwire Voltage Drop Calculator](https://www.southwire.com/calculator-vdrop)

Got the appetite for a small solar inverter? :)

Comment: I get 5.15% voltage drop on #2 Al at 12A (which is all you can actually draw continuously on a 15A breaker). 2-2-2 AL URD is "only" about $1/ft from HD. https://www.calculator.net/voltage-drop-calculator.html?necmaterial=aluminum&necwiresize=7&necconduit=steel&necpf=0.85&material=copper&wiresize=0.4066&resistance=1.2&resistanceunit=okm&voltage=120&phase=ac&noofconductor=1&distance=850&distanceunit=feet&amperes=12&x=48&y=19&ctype=nec

Comment: The best bet may be to get another meter installed but that is between you and the power company.